# How do I embed Plotly charts exported as HTML in Powerpoint?

Tags: python, plotly, powerpoint

I am aware of adding URL to PPT, but due to certain privacy issues that cannot be done.
Is there any other way to import plotly charts to ppt? or any equivalent open source app that can be used?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- it's pretty straight forward to save as a static image https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/
- create a powerpoint https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#
- I don't have powerpoint or a Windows o/s.  It's not clear that powerpoint works with active HTML

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "time": pd.date_range("1-Jul-2021", periods=200, freq="1H"),
        "desired_light": np.random.choice(["ON", "OFF"], 200),
    })

# build a figure
fig = px.bar(df, x="time", color="desired_light", height=400, title="Restaurant bills")
# export fingure as a static file: https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/
fname = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO.png")
fig.write_image(fname)

# create a powerpoint from an image: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

left = top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(str(fname), left, top)


prs.save(Path.cwd().joinpath('SO.pptx'))
```