# How can i import a plotly graph into my ppt file (with pypptx)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, python-pptx, plotly.graph-objects

I have to do a complicated graph on a ppt. Of course i started with the pyppt library  but there is very little documentation and you quickly find yourself stuck/

So i did my graph with plotly.graph (i have never done graphs) and i want to import it in my ppt file.

How can i do?

there is my graph:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches


from cgitb import text
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


def test_function(Class):
    labels = [5, 17, 39]


    widths = np.array([10,20,10])

    data = {
        "x1": [75,75,30],
        "x2": [75,0,45],
        "x3": [0,75,75],
    }

    x = [0, 4 , 12]
    fig = go.Figure()

    color = {
        "x1": '#E5EBF7',
        "x2":  '#D9CD9F',
        "x3":  '#F7F4E9',
    }
    for key in data:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(
            name=key,
            y=data[key],
            x= labels,

            width=widths,
            offset=0,
            customdata=np.transpose([labels, widths*data[key]]),
            texttemplate="%{y} x %{width} =<br>%{customdata[1]}",
            
            marker_color = color[key],
            textfont_color="white",
            textposition="inside",
            textangle=0,
            
            
            # hovertemplate="<br>".join([
            #     "label: %{customdata[0]}",
            #     "width: %{width}",
            #     "height: %{y}",
            #     "area: %{customdata[1]}",
            # ])
        ))



    fig.update_layout({
        'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        })


    #les lignes
    fig.add_shape( # add a horizontal "target" line
        type="line", line_color="black", line_width=3, opacity=1,
        x0=0, x1=55, y0=0, y1=0
    )
    fig.add_shape( # add a vertigal "target" line
        type="line", line_color="black", line_width=3, opacity=1,
        x0=4.5, x1=4.5, y0=0, y1=150
    )


    fig.add_shape( # add a lignes premier block line
        type="line", line_color="black", line_width=3, opacity=1, line_dash="dot",
        x0=5, x1=15, y0=75, y1=75
    )

    fig.add_shape( # add la ligne horizontale deuxieme block line
        type="line", line_color="black", line_width=3, opacity=1, line_dash="dot",
        x0=17, x1=37, y0=75, y1=75
    )


    fig.add_shape( # add la ligne horizontale deuxieme block line degressive
        type="line", line_color="green", line_width=3, opacity=1, line_dash="dot",
        x0=17, x1=37, y0=100, y1=77.5
    )


    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[17,37,37,17],
                            y=[100,77.5,75,75],
                            fill='toself',
                            fillcolor='#D9CD9F',
                            line=dict(width=0),
                            showlegend=False,
                            mode='lines'))


    fig.add_shape( # add la ligne horizontale troisieme block line
        type="line", line_color="black", line_width=3, opacity=1, line_dash="dot",
        x0=39, x1=49, y0=75, y1=75
    )



    #ici on remplace les valeurs x (ecrites abcisses(ne plus avoir 10 20 30 40 mais trimestre1 etc)) (hard codées)
    fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=0,
                    tickmode = 'array',
                    tickvals = [10, 27, 45],
                    ticktext= ["Trimestre 1 à 3", "Trimestre 4 a 39", "Trimestre 40"])


    fig.update_yaxes(tickangle=0,
                    tickmode = 'array',
                    tickvals = [0, 30, 75, 100],
                    ticktext= ["0%","30%", "75%", "Niveau de<br> Référence(100%)"],
                    ),
                    


    # fig.update_yaxes(tickangle=0,
    #                  tickmode = 'array',
    #                 tickvals = [30],
    #                 color= "red"
    #                  ),

    fig.update_layout(barmode="stack",uniformtext=dict(mode="hide", minsize=10),
    )



    #ICI FAIRE EN SORTE S IL Y A 2 OU 3 BLOCS (OU MANIERE DYNAMIQUE MAIS JE N Y ARRIVE PAS)

    #le premier parametre de range x, permet de mettre ou non un blanc entre le 0 et le premier bloc
    fig.update_xaxes(range=[4,55])
    fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,130])

    # fig.show()
    return(fig)



# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
test = test_function(slide)
```

[image]

I would like to import the graph (he doesn't have to be interactive) in my ppt file but not as a picture.

Is there a way to do that? If its not possible, do you think i can do the same graph with the pyppt api?

If it doesn't work. Do i have to import it as a picture.

Thanks for your reading!

Comment: How about saving the created graph as an image and importing it into PowerPoint? [https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#write-image-file](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#write-image-file)

Comment: I can't save as an image, i have to change the text on the ppt after it

Comment: previous answer that puts a plotly figure in a powerpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559750/how-do-i-embed-plotly-charts-exported-as-html-in-powerpoint it's an image,  I've not found a way to include active html